# Using a VHDL UCF file, how do I use the info inside to complete my VHDL FPGA implementation

Tags: vhdl, xilinx

I am a new VHDL user, programming a FPGA to control RGB LEDS. I have completed the actual entity and related architecture and also simulated in a test bench using Xilinx.
I now have to complete the top layer. How do I use the info below to get the ports from my block containing the LED operations to the actual pins?

```
## LEDS
NET RGB_LED<1><0>           IOSTANDARD = LVCMOS25;
NET RGB_LED<1><0>           LOC = AR29;#
NET RGB_LED<1><1>           IOSTANDARD = LVCMOS25;
NET RGB_LED<1><1>           LOC = AR28;#
NET RGB_LED<1><2>           IOSTANDARD = LVCMOS25;
NET RGB_LED<1><2>           LOC = AT14;#
NET RGB_LED<2><0>           IOSTANDARD = LVCMOS25;
NET RGB_LED<2><0>           LOC = AR14;#
NET RGB_LED<2><1>           IOSTANDARD = LVCMOS25;
```

the output port of the block instantiated in the top level is of a custom type that I included in a package as follows:

```
type LED_Array_Port is array (0 to 9) of std_logic_vector ( 2 downto 0);
```

There are thus 9 LEDs each with a R,G and B pin
How do actually get the output ports of my entity (already declared and instantiated in the top level) connected to pins on the FPGA?

Comment: One hint is to let the tools generate an UCF for you : e.g. place a few pins in the floorplanner. Don't worry if the pins are in the wrong place : what you're after is the syntax it uses for your custom port. Then you can edit it as you want.

Answer (score 1):

You UCF file is the  right place to do this. If you are having trouble getting what you showed above working, then I would've commend removing that special user defined type from your top levels entity. I suspect that the tools do not know what to do with that and are unable to match up your UCF constraints with any of your top level entity signals. Just make the top level type std_logic or std_logic_vector and see if that helps.

Comment: I now realize that I probably need to use tools to generate the UCF, rather than trying to start from scratch. Managed to get the custom type working by simply referencing as a 2D array i.e. <2><1>.